# JVM memory dump

Tags: java, tomcat, dump

We have Tomcat 7 and Java 7 running our application.

The last days we got a lot of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` errors.

So I added to `/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/tomcat7.conf` in `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
# Use JAVA_OPTS to set java.library.path for libtcnative.so
JAVA_OPTS="[...] -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/jvm_crash.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/ec2-user/dumps"
```

But `/var/log/jvm_crash.log` is empty and there are no `*.hprof` files anywhere (not only in `/home/ec2-user/dumps`, where I would expect them to be).

What did I miss here?

Comment: I suggest you to check your memory allocated for tomcat first, which contains PermGen size and memory. You can increase that. Also check for java heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to solve your memory leak problem, you could use [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/). It should just be located at `JDK_HOME/bin/jvisualvm.exe`.

With this tool, one thing you could do is track what `Object` has the most number of instances and those objects that are still present in the memory even though not used anymore.

This [video](https://visualvm.java.net/gettingstarted.html) should help you get started.